# How to fill the primeng <p-datatable> with FirebaseObservableList?

Tags: angular, firebase, web, primeng

I´m trying to fill my datatable () with my firebase database content. But I don´t know how to use the *ngFor like I used in a normal table.
The normal way is done:

```
<tr *ngFor="let docu of documentos | async">
  <td>{{docu.nombre}}</td>
  <td>{{docu.tipoDocumento}}</td>
  <td  >{{docu.usuario}}</td>
  <td  >{{docu.grupo}}</td>
  <td width="20%"><a class="btn btn-success" target="_blank" href="{{docu.enlaceDescarga}}">Ver</a></td>
</tr>
```

It fills perfectly.
But now I want to use PrimeNG

```
<p-dataTable [value]="" *ngFor='let docu of documentos | async'>
<p-column field={{docu.nombre}} header="Nombre"></p-column>
<p-column field="year" header="Tipo"></p-column>
<p-column field="brand" header="Permiso de usuario"></p-column>
<p-column field="color" header="Permiso de grupo"></p-column>
<p-column field="color" header="Enlace"></p-column></p-dataTable>
```

My problen is [value], I don´t know how to fill an array with a FirebaseObservableList.
I retrieve the the list with this:

```
documentos: FirebaseListObservable<any> = af.database.list('/Documentos');
```

> af is my AngularFire on constructor.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the below code:PrimeFace table the value contains the list of values so the prime face will take care of looping

```
<p-dataTable [value]="documentos|async">
<p-column field="nombre" header="Nombre"></p-column>
<p-column field="year" header="Tipo"></p-column>
<p-column field="brand" header="Permiso de usuario"></p-column>
<p-column field="color" header="Permiso de grupo"></p-column>
<p-column field="color" header="Enlace"></p-column></p-dataTable>
```

Comment: Yep I tried that before and i receive the same error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'               I think i have to use ngFor but I don´t know how

Comment: It´s not an object, it´s a AngularFire Observable List, that´s my problem

Comment: Try to use like this <p-dataTable [value]="documentos|async">

Comment: Mmm It work dude, ty but it only work on the header ;-; `<p-dataTable [value]="documentos|async">
  <p-column *ngFor='let docu of documentos | async' field={{docu.usuario}} header={{docu.usuario}}></p-column>
</p-dataTable>`

Comment: <p-dataTable [value]="documentos|async"> <p-column field="documentos.usuario" header=documentos.usuario></p-column> </p-dataTable>

Comment: It works! With a little bit more changes that I don´t really understand (but it works haha)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <p-dataTable [value]="documentos | async" align="center" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [globalFilter]="gb" #dt>
<p-column field="nombre" header="Nombre" [sortable]=true [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Buscar"></p-column>
<p-column field="tipoDocumento" header="Tipo documento" [sortable]=true></p-column>
<p-column field="usuario" header="Permisos de usuario" [sortable]=true [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Buscar"></p-column>
<p-column field="grupo" header="Permisos de grupo " [sortable]=true [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Buscar"></p-column>
<p-column field="enlaceDescarga" header="Enlace"></p-column>
```